# Sibling components sharing state instead of have individual one. Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, frontend

I wrote component that upload file to the server. It accepts external parameters and has internal one like `const a = ref<>();`. Then I create multiple instances of it in parent, and give them different props, but they are bugging and share one state.

[image: img]

I transfer to children different props, but even if I'll give them same props, they're not supposed to share internal state variables like `IsActive`, but they do.

ParentComponent.vue

```
<el-form ...>
  <el-tabs>
    <el-tab-pane>
      <el-form-item>
        <file-uploader
                :fileList="itemODS.tech_cond_files"
                @updateFiles="
                  async (files) => {
                    itemODS.tech_cond_files = files;
                    const response = await saveOdsOisId({
                      id: itemODS.id,
                      ois_id: itemODS.ois_id,
                      tech_cond_files: itemODS.tech_cond_files,
                    });
                  }
                "
              ></file-uploader>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item>
        <file-uploader
              :fileList="itemODS.project_files"
              @updateFiles="
                async (files) => {
                  itemODS.project_files = files;
                  const response = await saveOdsOisId({
                    id: itemODS.id,
                    ois_id: itemODS.ois_id,
                    project_files: itemODS.project_files,
                  });
                }
              "
              ></file-uploader>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
</el-form>
```

fileUploader.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="content" draggable="false" :class="getContentClass()">
      <input <...>/>

      <el-table :data="localFileList" style="width: 100%">
        <el-table-column prop="name">
          <template #default="scope">
            <span class="el-link" @click="handleFileClick(scope.row)">{{
              scope.row.name
            }}</span>
          </template>
        <el-table-column .../>
      </el-table>
      <button .../>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from "vue";
<...>

const localFileList = ref<FileEmbed[]>([]);
const fileService = useFileService();
const overlay = ref<HTMLElement>();
const isActove = ref<boolean>(false);
<...>


const props = defineProps<{
  fileList: FileEmbed[];
  keepDeletedFile?: boolean;
}>();

watch(
  () => props.fileList.length,
  () => {
    localFileList.value = props.fileList;
  }
);
const emit = defineEmits<{
  updateFiles: [files: FileEmbed[]];
}>();

async function uploadFile(event: Event) {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  if (target.files != null && target.files.length >= 0) {
    const file = await fileService.uploadFile(target.files[0]);
    localFileList.value.push(file);
    emit("updateFiles", localFileList.value);
  }
}

function handleDelete(index: number) {
  <...>
  emit("updateFiles", localFileList.value);
}
</script>
```

[link](https://element-plus.run/#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)

Comment: Can you create a [playground](https://element-plus.run) where the problem can be observed?

Comment: Ok, i'll try to

Comment: You can just put it in the question, that's easiest

Comment: @MoritzRingler, yeah, thats actualy good idea. Done

Comment: I did some mistakes while creating a playground, like same id and wrong target in callback. Now i fixed them and changed the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you use `document.getElementById()` on non-unique ids - having several components means having several elements with the same id, and `document.getElementById()` will always give you the first, no matter from which component you call it.

To access HTML elements in Vue, use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) instead of `document.getElementById()`, just assign a `ref` attribute to the element:

```
<input ref="uploader" .../>
```

and then in the script, declare a ref with the name passed to the `ref` attribute:

```
const uploader = ref()
```

Vue will then bind the HTML element to the variable.

See [playground with refs](https://element-plus.run/#eyJzcmMvQXBwLnZ1ZSI6IjxzY3JpcHQgc2V0dXAgbGFuZz1cInRzXCI+XG5pbXBvcnQgeyBvbk1vdW50ZWQsIHJlZiwgdmVyc2lvbiBhcyB2dWVWZXJzaW9uIH0gZnJvbSAndnVlJ1xuaW1wb3J0IHsgdmVyc2lvbiBhcyBlcFZlcnNpb24gfSBmcm9tICdlbGVtZW50LXBsdXMnXG5pbXBvcnQgRmlsZVVwbG9hZGVyIGZyb20gJy4vRmlsZVVwbG9hZGVyLnZ1ZSc7XG5pbXBvcnQgTXlQYWdlIGZyb20gJy4vTXlQYWdlLnZ1ZSc7XG5pbXBvcnQgeyBFbGVtZW50UGx1cyB9IGZyb20gJ0BlbGVtZW50LXBsdXMvaWNvbnMtdnVlJ1xuXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cblxuXG48dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gIDxNeVBhZ2UgLz5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7fVxufSIsInRzY29uZmlnLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiY29tcGlsZXJPcHRpb25zXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImFsbG93SnNcIjogdHJ1ZSxcbiAgICBcImNoZWNrSnNcIjogdHJ1ZSxcbiAgICBcImpzeFwiOiBcInByZXNlcnZlXCIsXG4gICAgXCJ0YXJnZXRcIjogXCJFU05leHRcIixcbiAgICBcIm1vZHVsZVwiOiBcIkVTTmV4dFwiLFxuICAgIFwibW9kdWxlUmVzb2x1dGlvblwiOiBcIkJ1bmRsZXJcIixcbiAgICBcImFsbG93SW1wb3J0aW5nVHNFeHRlbnNpb25zXCI6IHRydWUsXG4gICAgXCJ0eXBlc1wiOiBbXCJlbGVtZW50LXBsdXMvZ2xvYmFsLmQudHNcIl1cbiAgfSxcbiAgXCJ2dWVDb21waWxlck9wdGlvbnNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidGFyZ2V0XCI6IDMuM1xuICB9XG59XG4iLCJzcmMvRmlsZVVwbG9hZGVyLnZ1ZSI6Ijx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz1cIm1haW5cIj5cbiAgICA8ZGl2IHJlZj1cImNvbnRlbnRcIiBkcmFnZ2FibGU9XCJmYWxzZVwiIDpjbGFzcz1cImdldENvbnRlbnRDbGFzcygpXCI+XG4gICAgICA8aW5wdXRcbiAgICAgICAgcmVmPVwidXBsb2FkZXJcIlxuICAgICAgICBkcmFnZ2FibGU9XCJmYWxzZVwiXG4gICAgICAgIHR5cGU9XCJmaWxlXCJcbiAgICAgICAgc3R5bGU9XCJkaXNwbGF5OiBub25lXCJcbiAgICAgICAgQGNoYW5nZT1cInVwbG9hZEZpbGVcIlxuICAgICAgLz5cblxuICAgICAgPGVsLXRhYmxlIDpkYXRhPVwibG9jYWxGaWxlTGlzdFwiIHN0eWxlPVwid2lkdGg6IDEwMCVcIj5cbiAgICAgICAgPGVsLXRhYmxlLWNvbHVtbiBwcm9wPVwibmFtZVwiIGxhYmVsPVwiTmFtZVwiIG1pbi13aWR0aD1cIjQwXCI+XG4gICAgICAgICAgPHRlbXBsYXRlICNkZWZhdWx0PVwic2NvcGVcIj5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGNsYXNzPVwiZWwtbGlua1wiPnt7XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIHNjb3BlLnJvdy5uYW1lXG4gICAgICAgICAgICB9fTwvc3Bhbj5cbiAgICAgICAgICA8L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuICAgICAgICA8L2VsLXRhYmxlLWNvbHVtbj5cbiAgICAgICAgPGVsLXRhYmxlLWNvbHVtbiBwcm9wPVwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdFwiIGxhYmVsPVwiRGF0ZVwiIG1pbi13aWR0aD1cIjE1XCI+XG4gICAgICAgICAgPHRlbXBsYXRlICNkZWZhdWx0PVwic2NvcGVcIj5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxzcGFuPnt7IG5ldyBEYXRlKHNjb3BlLnJvdy5jcmVhdGVkX2F0KS50b0xvY2FsZVN0cmluZygpIH19PC9zcGFuPlxuICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gICAgICAgIDwvZWwtdGFibGUtY29sdW1uPlxuICAgICAgICA8ZWwtdGFibGUtY29sdW1uIHdpZHRoPVwiNjBweFwiPlxuICAgICAgICAgIDx0ZW1wbGF0ZSAjZGVmYXVsdD1cInNjb3BlXCI+XG4gICAgICAgICAgICA8ZWwtYnV0dG9uXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIHN0eWxlPVwiaGVpZ2h0OiAzNXB4OyB3aWR0aDogMzVweDsgcGFkZGluZzogOHB4IDhweCA4cHggOHB4XCJcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgdHlwZT1cImRhbmdlclwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIEBjbGljaz1cImhhbmRsZURlbGV0ZShzY29wZS4kaW5kZXgpXCJcbiAgICAgICAgICAgID5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvZWwtYnV0dG9uPlxuICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gICAgICAgIDwvZWwtdGFibGUtY29sdW1uPlxuICAgICAgPC9lbC10YWJsZT5cbiAgICAgIDxidXR0b24gcmVmPVwiYnV0dG9uXCIgZHJhZ2dhYmxlPVwiZmFsc2VcIiBjbGFzcz1cInBsdXMtYnV0dG9uXCI+XG4gICAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGNsYXNzPVwicGx1cy1pY29uXCI+Kzwvc3Bhbj5cbiAgICAgIDwvYnV0dG9uPlxuICAgIDwvZGl2PlxuXG4gICAgPGRpdiByZWY9XCJvdmVybGF5XCIgZHJhZ2dhYmxlPVwiZmFsc2VcIiA6Y2xhc3M9XCJnZXRPdmVybGF5Q2xhc3MoKVwiPlxuICAgICAgPHNwYW4+IERyYWcgaGVyZSBzb21lIGZpbGVzIDwvc3Bhbj5cbiAgICA8L2Rpdj5cbiAgPC9kaXY+XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuPHNjcmlwdCBsYW5nPVwidHNcIiBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IG9uTW91bnRlZCwgcmVmLCB3YXRjaCB9IGZyb20gXCJ2dWVcIjtcbmludGVyZmFjZSBGaWxlRW1iZWQge1xuICBpZDogbnVtYmVyO1xuICBuYW1lOiBzdHJpbmc7XG4gIHBhdGg6IHN0cmluZztcbiAgbWltZXR5cGU6IHN0cmluZztcbiAgY3JlYXRlZF9hdDogc3RyaW5nO1xufVxuY29uc3QgbG9jYWxGaWxlTGlzdCA9IHJlZjxGaWxlRW1iZWRbXT4oW10pO1xuY29uc3QgaXNBY3RpdmUgPSByZWY8Ym9vbGVhbj4oZmFsc2UpO1xuXG5jb25zdCBvdmVybGF5ID0gcmVmPEhUTUxFbGVtZW50PigpO1xuY29uc3QgY29udGVudCA9IHJlZjxIVE1MRWxlbWVudD4oKTtcbmNvbnN0IHVwbG9hZGVyID0gcmVmPEhUTUxJbnB1dEVsZW1lbnQ+KCk7XG5jb25zdCBidXR0b24gPSByZWY8SFRNTEVsZW1lbnQ+KCk7XG5cbmNvbnN0IGljb24gPSByZWY8SFRNTEVsZW1lbnQ+KCk7XG5cbmNvbnN0IHByb3BzID0gZGVmaW5lUHJvcHM8e1xuICBmaWxlTGlzdDogRmlsZUVtYmVkW107XG4gIGtlZXBEZWxldGVkRmlsZT86IGJvb2xlYW47XG59PigpO1xuXG53YXRjaChcbiAgKCkgPT4gcHJvcHMuZmlsZUxpc3QubGVuZ3RoLFxuICAoKSA9PiB7XG4gICAgbG9jYWxGaWxlTGlzdC52YWx1ZSA9IHByb3BzLmZpbGVMaXN0O1xuICB9XG4pO1xuY29uc3QgZW1pdCA9IGRlZmluZUVtaXRzPHtcbiAgdXBkYXRlRmlsZXM6IFtmaWxlczogRmlsZUVtYmVkW11dO1xufT4oKTtcbi8qKlxuKiBFbXB0eSAtIHNob3dzIG92ZXJsYXkgd2l0aCBoYWxmIG9wYWNpdHlcbiogTm90IEVtcHR5IC0gdGFibGUgd2l0aCBmaWxlc1xuKiBPbkRyYWcgLSBzaG93cyBvdmVybGF5LCB0aGF0IHRha2VzIGZpbGVcbiovXG53YXRjaChcbiAgKCkgPT4gb3ZlcmxheS52YWx1ZSxcbiAgKCkgPT4ge1xuICAgIGlmIChvdmVybGF5LnZhbHVlICE9IHVuZGVmaW5lZCkge1xuICAgICAgb3ZlcmxheS52YWx1ZS5hZGRFdmVudExpc3RlbmVyKFwiZHJhZ292ZXJcIiwgKGV2ZW50KSA9PiB7XG4gICAgICAgIGV2ZW50LnByZXZlbnREZWZhdWx0KCk7XG4gICAgICAgIGV2ZW50LnN0b3BQcm9wYWdhdGlvbigpO1xuICAgICAgfSk7XG4gICAgICBvdmVybGF5LnZhbHVlLmFkZEV2ZW50TGlzdGVuZXIoXCJkcmFnbGVhdmVcIiwgKGV2ZW50KSA9PiB7XG4gICAgICAgIGV2ZW50LnByZXZlbnREZWZhdWx0KCk7XG4gICAgICAgIGNvbnN0IGN1cnJlbnQgPSBldmVudC5jdXJyZW50VGFyZ2V0IGFzIEhUTUxFbGVtZW50O1xuICAgICAgICBjb25zdCB0YXJnZXQgPSBldmVudC5yZWxhdGVkVGFyZ2V0IGFzIEhUTUxFbGVtZW50O1xuICAgICAgICBpZiAoIXRhcmdldCB8fCAoY3VycmVudCAhPSBudWxsICYmICFjdXJyZW50LmNvbnRhaW5zKHRhcmdldCkpKSB7XG4gICAgICAgICAgaXNBY3RpdmUudmFsdWUgPSBmYWxzZTtcbiAgICAgICAgfVxuICAgICAgfSk7XG4gICAgICBvdmVybGF5LnZhbHVlLmFkZEV2ZW50TGlzdGVuZXIoXCJkcm9wXCIsIGFzeW5jIChldmVudCkgPT4ge1xuICAgICAgICBldmVudC5wcmV2ZW50RGVmYXVsdCgpO1xuICAgICAgICBpc0FjdGl2ZS52YWx1ZSA9IGZhbHNlO1xuICAgICAgICBjb25zdCBmaWxlOiBGaWxlRW1iZWQgPSB7IGlkOiAwLCBuYW1lOiBcIm5hbWVcIiwgcGF0aDogXCJwYXRoXCIsIG1pbWV0eXBlOiBcInR5cGVcIiwgY3JlYXRlZF9hdDogXCJkYXRlXCJ9O1xuICAgICAgICBsb2NhbEZpbGVMaXN0LnZhbHVlLnB1c2goZmlsZSk7XG4gICAgICAgIGVtaXQoXCJ1cGRhdGVGaWxlc1wiLCBsb2NhbEZpbGVMaXN0LnZhbHVlKTtcbiAgICAgIH0pO1xuICAgICAgb3ZlcmxheS52YWx1ZT8uYWRkRXZlbnRMaXN0ZW5lcihcImNsaWNrXCIsIGFzeW5jIChldmVudCkgPT4ge1xuICAgICAgICB1cGxvYWRlci52YWx1ZT8uY2xpY2soKTtcbiAgICAgIH0pO1xuICAgIH1cbiAgfVxuKTtcbndhdGNoKFxuICAoKSA9PiBjb250ZW50LnZhbHVlLFxuICAoKSA9PiB7XG4gICAgaWYgKGNvbnRlbnQudmFsdWUgIT0gdW5kZWZpbmVkKSB7XG4gICAgICBjb250ZW50LnZhbHVlLmFkZEV2ZW50TGlzdGVuZXIoXCJkcmFnb3ZlclwiLCAoZXZlbnQpID0+IHtcbiAgICAgICAgZXZlbnQucHJldmVudERlZmF1bHQoKTtcbiAgICAgIH0pO1xuICAgICAgY29udGVudC52YWx1ZS5hZGRFdmVudExpc3RlbmVyKFwiZHJhZ2VudGVyXCIsIChldmVudCkgPT4ge1xuICAgICAgICBldmVudC5wcmV2ZW50RGVmYXVsdCgpO1xuICAgICAgICBpc0FjdGl2ZS52YWx1ZSA9IHRydWU7XG4gICAgICB9KTtcbiAgICB9XG4gIH1cbik7XG53YXRjaChcbiAgKCkgPT4gYnV0dG9uLnZhbHVlLFxuICAoKSA9PiB7XG4gICAgaWYgKGJ1dHRvbi52YWx1ZSAhPSB1bmRlZmluZWQpIHtcbiAgICAgIGJ1dHRvbi52YWx1ZS5hZGRFdmVudExpc3RlbmVyKFwiY2xpY2tcIiwgKGV2ZW50KSA9PiB7XG4gICAgICAgIGV2ZW50LnByZXZlbnREZWZhdWx0KCk7XG4gICAgICAgIHVwbG9hZGVyLnZhbHVlPy5jbGljaygpO1xuICAgICAgfSk7XG4gICAgfVxuICB9XG4pO1xuXG5hc3luYyBmdW5jdGlvbiB1cGxvYWRGaWxlKGV2ZW50OiBFdmVudCkge1xuICBjb25zdCB0YXJnZXQgPSBldmVudC50YXJnZXQgYXMgSFRNTElucHV0RWxlbWVudDtcbiAgaWYgKHRhcmdldC5maWxlcyAhPSBudWxsICYmIHRhcmdldC5maWxlcy5sZW5ndGggPj0gMCkge1xuICAgIGNvbnN0IGZpbGU6IEZpbGVFbWJlZCA9IHsgaWQ6IDAsIG5hbWU6IFwibmFtZVwiLCBwYXRoOiBcInBhdGhcIiwgbWltZXR5cGU6IFwidHlwZVwiLCBjcmVhdGVkX2F0OiBcImRhdGVcIn1cbiAgICBsb2NhbEZpbGVMaXN0LnZhbHVlLnB1c2goZmlsZSk7XG4gICAgZW1pdChcInVwZGF0ZUZpbGVzXCIsIGxvY2FsRmlsZUxpc3QudmFsdWUpO1xuICB9XG59XG5cbmZ1bmN0aW9uIGhhbmRsZURlbGV0ZShpbmRleDogbnVtYmVyKSB7XG4gIGxvY2FsRmlsZUxpc3QudmFsdWUuc3BsaWNlKGluZGV4LCAxKTtcbiAgZW1pdChcInVwZGF0ZUZpbGVzXCIsIGxvY2FsRmlsZUxpc3QudmFsdWUpO1xufVxuXG5mdW5jdGlvbiBnZXRDb250ZW50Q2xhc3MoKSB7XG4gIGlmIChsb2NhbEZpbGVMaXN0LnZhbHVlLmxlbmd0aCA+IDApIHtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gXCJjb250ZW50XCI7XG4gIH0gZWxzZSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIFwiY29udGVudEhpZGRlblwiO1xuICB9XG59XG5cbmZ1bmN0aW9uIGdldE92ZXJsYXlDbGFzcygpIHtcbiAgaWYgKGlzQWN0aXZlLnZhbHVlKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIFwib3ZlcmxheUFjdGl2ZVwiO1xuICB9IGVsc2UgaWYgKCFpc0FjdGl2ZS52YWx1ZSAmJiBsb2NhbEZpbGVMaXN0LnZhbHVlLmxlbmd0aCA9PSAwKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIFwib3ZlcmxheUluYWN0aXZlXCI7XG4gIH0gZWxzZSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIFwib3ZlcmxheUhpZGRlblwiO1xuICB9XG59XG5cbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuXG48c3R5bGU+XG4ubWFpbiB7XG4gIHBvc2l0aW9uOiByZWxhdGl2ZTtcbiAgei1pbmRleDogMDtcbiAgYm94LXNoYWRvdzogMCAwIDAgMXB4ICNkY2RmZTY7XG4gIGJvcmRlci1yYWRpdXM6IDNweDtcbiAgaGVpZ2h0OiAyMDBweDtcbn1cblxuLm1haW46aG92ZXIge1xuICBib3gtc2hhZG93OiAwIDAgMCAxcHggI2JjYmZjNDtcbn1cblxuLmNvbnRlbnQge1xuICBwb3NpdGlvbjogcmVsYXRpdmU7XG4gIGhlaWdodDogMTAwJTtcbiAgd2lkdGg6IDEwMCU7XG4gIG92ZXJmbG93LXk6IHNjcm9sbDtcbiAgcGFkZGluZzogM3B4O1xuICB6LWluZGV4OiAxO1xufVxuXG4uY29udGVudEhpZGRlbiB7XG4gIGRpc3BsYXk6IG5vbmU7XG59XG5cbi5vdmVybGF5QWN0aXZlIHtcbiAgcG9zaXRpb246IGFic29sdXRlO1xuICB0b3A6IDA7XG4gIGxlZnQ6IDA7XG4gIGhlaWdodDogMTAwJTtcbiAgd2lkdGg6IDEwMCU7XG4gIGRpc3BsYXk6IGZsZXg7XG4gIGZsZXgtZGlyZWN0aW9uOiBjb2x1bW47XG4gIGFsaWduLWl0ZW1zOiBjZW50ZXI7XG4gIGFsaWduLWNvbnRlbnQ6IGNlbnRlcjtcbiAganVzdGlmeS1jb250ZW50OiBjZW50ZXI7XG4gIG92ZXJmbG93OiBoaWRkZW47XG4gIG9wYWNpdHk6IDAuNztcbiAgYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjogd2hpdGU7XG4gIHotaW5kZXg6IDI7XG59XG5cbi5vdmVybGF5SW5hY3RpdmUge1xuICBwb3NpdGlvbjogYWJzb2x1dGU7XG4gIHRvcDogMDtcbiAgbGVmdDogMDtcbiAgaGVpZ2h0OiAxMDAlO1xuICB3aWR0aDogMTAwJTtcbiAgZGlzcGxheTogZmxleDtcbiAgZmxleC1kaXJlY3Rpb246IGNvbHVtbjtcbiAgYWxpZ24taXRlbXM6IGNlbnRlcjtcbiAgYWxpZ24tY29udGVudDogY2VudGVyO1xuICBqdXN0aWZ5LWNvbnRlbnQ6IGNlbnRlcjtcbiAgb3ZlcmZsb3c6IGhpZGRlbjtcbiAgb3BhY2l0eTogMC41O1xuICB6LWluZGV4OiAyO1xufVxuXG4ub3ZlcmxheUhpZGRlbiB7XG4gIGRpc3BsYXk6IG5vbmU7XG59XG5cbi5wbHVzLWJ1dHRvbiB7XG4gIGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6ICM0MDllZmY7XG4gIGJvcmRlcjogbm9uZTtcbiAgbWFyZ2luOiAzcHggMHB4IDNweCAwcHg7XG4gIGJvcmRlci1yYWRpdXM6IDhweDtcbiAgYm94LXNoYWRvdzogMHB4IDJweCA0cHggcmdiYSgwLCAwLCAwLCAwLjI1KTtcbiAgY3Vyc29yOiBwb2ludGVyO1xuICBoZWlnaHQ6IDMycHg7XG4gIHdpZHRoOiAxMDAlO1xufVxuXG4ucGx1cy1idXR0b246aG92ZXIge1xuICBiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiAjNzliYWZjO1xufVxuXG4ucGx1cy1pY29uIHtcbiAgY29sb3I6ICNmZmZmZmY7XG4gIGZvbnQtc2l6ZTogMjRweDtcbn1cbjwvc3R5bGU+XG4iLCJzcmMvTXlQYWdlLnZ1ZSI6Ijx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgPGVsLWZvcm1cbiAgICBsYWJlbC13aWR0aD1cIjE1MHB4XCJcbiAgPlxuICAgIDxlbC10YWJzIHR5cGU9XCJib3JkZXItY2FyZFwiPlxuICAgICAgPGVsLXRhYi1wYW5lIGxhYmVsPVwiVGFiT25lXCI+XG4gICAgICAgIDxkaXYgdi1zaG93PVwiYS5sZW5ndGg+MFwiPlxuICAgICAgICAgIDxlbC1mb3JtLWl0ZW0gbGFiZWw9XCJGaXJzdFVwbG9hZFwiPlxuICAgICAgICAgICAgPGVsLWNvbD5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPGZpbGUtdXBsb2FkZXJcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBpZD1cIm9uZVwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgOmZpbGVMaXN0PVwiYVwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgQHVwZGF0ZUZpbGVzPVwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBhc3luYyAoZmlsZXMpID0+IHtcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYSA9IGZpbGVzO1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgfVxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIFwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgID48L2ZpbGUtdXBsb2FkZXI+XG4gICAgICAgICAgICA8L2VsLWNvbD5cbiAgICAgICAgICA8L2VsLWZvcm0taXRlbT5cbiAgICAgICAgPC9kaXY+XG4gICAgICAgIDxlbC1mb3JtLWl0ZW1cbiAgICAgICAgICBsYWJlbD1cIlNlY29uZFVwbG9hZFwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgdi1pZj1cImIubGVuZ3RoPjBcIlxuICAgICAgICA+XG4gICAgICAgICAgPGVsLWNvbD5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxmaWxlLXVwbG9hZGVyXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgaWQ9XCJ0d29cIlxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDpmaWxlTGlzdD1cImJcIlxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIEB1cGRhdGVGaWxlcz1cIlxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgYXN5bmMgKGZpbGVzKSA9PiB7XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGIgPSBmaWxlcztcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIH1cbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBcIlxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICA+PC9maWxlLXVwbG9hZGVyPlxuICAgICAgICAgIDwvZWwtY29sPlxuICAgICAgICA8L2VsLWZvcm0taXRlbT5cbiAgICAgIDwvZWwtdGFiLXBhbmU+XG4gICAgICA8ZWwtdGFiLXBhbmUgbGFiZWw9XCJUYWJUd29cIj5cbiAgICAgICAgPGVsLWZvcm0taXRlbSBsYWJlbD1cIlRoaXJkVXBsb2FkXCI+XG4gICAgICAgICAgPGVsLWNvbD5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxmaWxlLXVwbG9hZGVyXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDpmaWxlTGlzdD1cImNcIlxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICBAdXBkYXRlRmlsZXM9XCJcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBhc3luYyAoZmlsZXMpID0+IHtcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGMgPSBmaWxlcztcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB9XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIFwiXG4gICAgICAgICAgICA+PC9maWxlLXVwbG9hZGVyPlxuICAgICAgICAgIDwvZWwtY29sPlxuICAgICAgICA8L2VsLWZvcm0taXRlbT5cbiAgICAgIDwvZWwtdGFiLXBhbmU+XG4gICAgPC9lbC10YWJzPlxuICA8L2VsLWZvcm0+XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuXG48c2NyaXB0IGxhbmc9XCJ0c1wiIHNldHVwPlxuaW1wb3J0IHsgb25Nb3VudGVkLCBQcm9wVHlwZSwgcmVmIH0gZnJvbSBcInZ1ZVwiO1xuaW1wb3J0IEZpbGVVcGxvYWRlciBmcm9tIFwiLi9GaWxlVXBsb2FkZXIudnVlXCI7XG5pbnRlcmZhY2UgRmlsZUVtYmVkIHtcbiAgaWQ6IG51bWJlcjtcbiAgbmFtZTogc3RyaW5nO1xuICBwYXRoOiBzdHJpbmc7XG4gIG1pbWV0eXBlOiBzdHJpbmc7XG4gIGNyZWF0ZWRfYXQ6IHN0cmluZztcbn1cbmNvbnN0IGEgPSByZWY8RmlsZUVtYmVkW10+KFtdKTtcbmNvbnN0IGIgPSByZWY8RmlsZUVtYmVkW10+KFtdKTtcbmNvbnN0IGMgPSByZWY8RmlsZUVtYmVkW10+KFtdKTtcblxuXG5jb25zdCBwcm9wcyA9IGRlZmluZVByb3BzKHtcbiAgZGVmYXVsdEZpbmRPcHRpb25zOiB7XG4gICAgcmVxdWlyZWQ6IGZhbHNlLFxuICAgIHR5cGU6IE9iamVjdCBhcyBQcm9wVHlwZTxSZWNvcmQ8c3RyaW5nLCBhbnk+PixcbiAgfSxcbn0pO1xuXG5vbk1vdW50ZWQoYXN5bmMgKCkgPT4ge1xuICAgIGEudmFsdWUgPSBbeyBpZDogMCwgbmFtZTogXCJuYW1lMVwiLCBwYXRoOiBcInBhdGgxXCIsIG1pbWV0eXBlOiBcInR5cGUxXCIsIGNyZWF0ZWRfYXQ6IFwiZGF0ZTFcIn0sIHsgaWQ6IDEsIG5hbWU6IFwibmFtZTJcIiwgcGF0aDogXCJwYXRoMlwiLCBtaW1ldHlwZTogXCJ0eXBlMlwiLCBjcmVhdGVkX2F0OiBcImRhdGUyXCJ9XTtcbiAgICBiLnZhbHVlID0gW3sgaWQ6IDIsIG5hbWU6IFwibmFtZTNcIiwgcGF0aDogXCJwYXRoM1wiLCBtaW1ldHlwZTogXCJ0eXBlM1wiLCBjcmVhdGVkX2F0OiBcImRhdGUzXCJ9LCB7IGlkOiAzLCBuYW1lOiBcIm5hbWU0XCIsIHBhdGg6IFwicGF0aDRcIiwgbWltZXR5cGU6IFwidHlwZTRcIiwgY3JlYXRlZF9hdDogXCJkYXRlNFwifV1cbiAgICBjLnZhbHVlID0gW3sgaWQ6IDQsIG5hbWU6IFwiYXNkXCIsIHBhdGg6IFwiYXNkXCIsIG1pbWV0eXBlOiBcImFzZFwiLCBjcmVhdGVkX2F0OiBcImFkZHNcIn0sIHsgaWQ6IDYsIG5hbWU6IFwiaGRmXCIsIHBhdGg6IFwiZGhmXCIsIG1pbWV0eXBlOiBcImRmaFwiLCBjcmVhdGVkX2F0OiBcImRoZGZcIn1dXG59KTtcblxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG5cbjxzdHlsZSBzY29wZWQ+XG4uZ3JpZC1jb250ZW50IHtcbiAgYm9yZGVyLXJhZGl1czogNHB4O1xuICBtaW4taGVpZ2h0OiAzNnB4O1xufVxuXG48L3N0eWxlPlxuIiwiX28iOnt9fQ==)

---

However, better yet, don't use direct DOM manipulation at all. Using template refs is necessary when you need to access element functionality (like getting the context from a canvas element). In almost all other cases, it goes against the design principles of Vue, which offers better mechanisms to achieve your goal.

For example, you use a ref on the file input element to trigger click events, which is fine, but all other elements are used to set listeners with `element.addEventListener()`, which you can do better by using the same [Vue syntax](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events) as you do with `@click` in the `<el-button>`.

See [playground without addEventListener](https://element-plus.run/#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)

---

So replacing the `getElementById()` statements with template refs, or even better, replacing the `addEventListener()` calls with Vue event listener statements should fix the issue.

Comment: Seems like it works now. Thank you!

Comment: That's great! If it helps, I have added a second playground

Comment: Wow, that's interesting and more clean solution, i'll try it, thank you.